# Switch to Django Custom User Model, Groups and Permissions

Tags: python, database, django, django-south, django-1.5

I updated my django 1.4 application with user profiles to use 1.5 Custom User Model.

```
#core/models.py

from django.contrib.auth.models import User, UserManager, BaseUserManager, AbstractUser

class MyUserManager(BaseUserManager):
    pass

class MyUser(AbstractUser):
    phone = models.CharField(blank = True, max_length = 18)
    completed_step = models.IntegerField(default = 0)
    objects = MyUserManager()
```

I wrote schema migrations for south and all data was imported successfully.

Otherwise, I have a problem with auth_group and auth_permision.
Django can't generate any additional tables, but when I want to get permissions or groups I have this SQL with JOIN to additional table:

```
 SELECT ...
      FROM "core_myuser"
      WHERE "core_myuser"."id" = 61 (8ms) Found 1 matching rows
 SELECT ...
      FROM "core_myuser"
      WHERE "core_myuser"."id" = 363 (1ms) Found 1 matching rows
 SELECT ...
      FROM "auth_group"
      INNER JOIN "core_myuser_groups" ON ("auth_group"."id" = "core_myuser_groups"."group_id")
      WHERE "core_myuser_groups"."myuser_id" = 363
```

With Internal Server Error

http://cl.ly/image/0W1G3F2S3f3X

Answer (score 0):

You have not created appropriate table in the database.
Make tables before switching user model:

```
python manage.py syncdb
#or if you're use south
python manage.py schemamigration core --initial
python manage.py migrate core
```

Then write custom migration script for you user data, or you'll lose it.

Look [this manual](http://django-authtools.readthedocs.org/en/latest/how-to/migrate-to-a-custom-user-model.html) and this [documentation](http://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/), it'll help you to understend what should be done.